# Why does OpenSSL use STACK_OF(X509) to verify signatures?

Tags: openssl, certificate

PKCS7 verification function has signature

`int PKCS7_verify(PKCS7 *p7, STACK_OF(X509) *certs, X509_STORE *store, BIO *indata, BIO *out, int flags);`

where `certs is a set of certificates in which to search for the signer's certificate.`

Why does OpenSSL use `STACK_OF()` for this "set of certificates", i.e. why stack-like ordering? Isn't `X509_STORE` the appropriate type for this?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does OpenSSL use STACK_OF() for this "set of certificates", i.e. why stack-like ordering? Isn't X509_STORE the appropriate type for this?

From the [`PKCS7_verify` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/PKCS7_verify.html):

> PKCS7_verify() verifies a PKCS#7 signedData structure... certs is a
>   set of certificates in which to search for the signer's certificate.
>   store is a trusted certificate store (used for chain verification).
>   indata is the signed data if the content is not present in p7 (that is
>   it is detached).

If I am not mistaken, (1) `certs` is a collection of end-entity certificates. Its a list of "who you trust". (2) `store` is a collection of CA certificates. Its a list of "who you delegate trust to".

Items (1) and (2) are not quite the same. Its not clear to me if/how they intersect because I don't use CMS and PKCS #7 too often. From the parenthesized *"chain verification"*, we know they are talking about public and private PKIs and path building. Shooting from the hip, I'm guessing its Web of Trust (item (1)) versus PKI hierarchy (item (2)).